# If $\alpha$, $\beta$ are roots of $\frac1{1-\sqrt{2}}x^2-(3+2\sqrt{2})x+1+\sqrt{2}=0$, then find $\alpha^2+\beta+\frac{1}{\alpha^2}-\frac{1}{\beta}$

Tags: calculus

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of this equation: $$\frac1{1-\sqrt{2}}x^2-\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)x+1+\sqrt{2}=0$$ then find the value of: $$\alpha^2+\beta+\frac{1}{\alpha^2}-\frac{1}{\beta}$$

Please do not use the $\Delta = b^2-4ac$ method. Use Vieta's formulas: $$S=\alpha+\beta=-\frac{b}{a} \qquad P=\alpha\beta=\frac{c}{a}$$

What i know are simple rules of quadratic equations like calculating delta and roots and also unities (unions) such as (x-a)(x+a)
I actually want to calculate using unities (without delta)and I don't have any ideas about how to solve . Please tell me how can I solve it using unities(and what kind of unities)!

Comment: Why do you repost your old question, which was put on hold (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2948859/if-alpha-beta-are-roots-of-frac11-sqrt2x2-32-sqrt2x1-sqrt) ? You should edit the old one.

Comment: @Ennar It appears that the linked question hasn't been answered, is closed, and has less context than this one.

Comment: @Theo, it also happens to be the same question the same user asked 17 hours ago. Instead of editing the question they asked a new one. Since when do we allow bypassing putting question on hold?

Comment: What I mean is that this and question 17 hours ago are not that much different in quality. It just happens that not the same users are active, apparently, so instead of downvotes, the same question gets answers.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

No need to calculate $\alpha$ and $\beta$:
$$\frac1{1-\sqrt{2}}x^2-(3+2\sqrt{2})x+1+\sqrt{2}=0 \Leftrightarrow x^2 + (1+\sqrt{2})x - 1 = 0 \Rightarrow $$

- $\alpha\beta = -1 \Rightarrow \alpha^2\beta^2 = 1$
- $\alpha + \beta = -(1 +\sqrt{2})$

$$\alpha^2 + \beta + \frac{1}{\alpha^2} - \frac{1}{\beta} \stackrel{-1 = \alpha\beta}{=}
\alpha^2 + \beta + \beta ^2 + \alpha = 
 \boxed{(\alpha + \beta)^2 - 2\alpha\beta + (\alpha + \beta)
}$$

Comment: @Dahaka: We have $$(x\color{blue}{-\alpha})(x\color{blue}{-\beta}) = x^2 \color{blue}{- (\alpha + \beta)}x + \color{blue}{\alpha\beta}$$
Now, read the corresponding relations from $$x^2 +(1+\sqrt{2})x - 1 = x^2  \color{blue}{-(-1-\sqrt{2})}x +\color{blue}{(- 1)}$$

Comment: @Dahaka, $-1/\beta = (\alpha\beta)/\beta = \alpha$ and similar for $1/\alpha^2 = \beta^2$.